# Singly linked list java

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

How can I make the output be sorted by score and alphabetically?

```
Arya 89
Raffi 89
Thoriq 89
Hasan 79
Husain 79
Krisna 90
```

**Sample Output 1**

```
1. Krisna 90
2. Arya 89
2. Raffi 89
2. Thoriq 89
3. Hasan 79
3. Husain 79
```

[`Wrong answer`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iBxS.png)
[`mycode1`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sx9Ix.png)
[`mycode2`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZLhm.png)

Specifically, I don't understand how to create the code to sort by name if the scores are the same.

Comment: You need to learn how this website works. Take the [tour], visit the [help] and read [ask]. Then [edit] your question and post your code as [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) **text** and **not** as an [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).